# Stored procedure is so slowly when using count distinct

Tags: mysql

When I run the stored procedure for the first time, it is so slow and the process lasts for 1 minute, and then I run it again and it lasts 10 seconds.

Following is my main sql statement, please help me to check out , thank you very much！

example 1

```
SELECT sql_no_cache view_address.is_facility,count(DISTINCT 
view_address.provider_id)as totalCount FROM pv_mview_provider_address view_address WHERE
view_address.network_group_id=5047 AND view_address.carrier_group_id=93 GROUP BY
view_address.is_facility;
```

explain:

example 2：

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE is_facility,count(distinct provider_id) FROM (SELECT 
view_address.provider_id,view_address.is_facility FROM pv_mview_provider_address
view_address WHERE view_address.network_group_id=5047 AND view_address.carrier_group_id=93
) as p GROUP BY is_facility
```

explain:

this sql will spend 10 s to load the data.
The table stores 4000,0000 rows.
Thank you very much！

Comment: example 2 explain:id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 PRIMARY <derived2> ALL     4787400 Using filesort
2 DERIVED view_address ref xie6_pv_mvw_prvdr_addrss xie6_pv_mvw_prvdr_addrss 5 const 4787400 Using where

Comment: example 1 explain:id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE view_address ref xie5_pv_mvw_prvdr_addrss,xie6_pv_mvw_prvdr_addrss,xie7_pv_mvw_prvdr_addrss xie6_pv_mvw_prvdr_addrss 5 const 4787400 Using where; Using filesort

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: Well, it has to read all 4 million (or 40 million?) rows from disk if you don't have a good `INDEX` on `network_group_id` and/or `carrier_group_id`. That takes time. Second time you do it, those rows are cached in memory, so much faster.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Please edit your post to keep only the relevant tags (I doubt that all of Java, MySQL and Oracle apply). Also please explain the unusual notation 4000,0000 or use standard notation - what is that, 40 million?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  thanks for your kindness, i am using mysql database. the data is more than 40 million .

Comment: @Andreas .  you are right, but,is there something wrong with this sql, can I improve it without adding the index. Thanks!

Comment: No. For that, you need an index. Your query is limited to `network_group_id = 5047 AND carrier_group_id = 93`, but without an index, the database has to scan the entire table to find those records. Think about an index in a book. With an index, you can quickly find the page(s) that are relevant. Without an index, you have to flip through all the pages on the book. That takes time *(and is boring/slow)*.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select sql_no_cache a.is_facility,
       count(distinct a.provider_id) as totalCount
from pv_mview_provider_address a
where a.network_group_id = 5047 and
      a.carrier_group_id = 93
group by a.is_facility;
```

You want an index.  The best index is `pv_mview_provider_address(network_group_id, carrier_group_id, is_facility)`.  However, if the reference in the `from` clause is a view and not a table, then you need to figure out what is happening with the view.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have no privilege to add the index (network_group_id, carrier_group_id, is_facility)...  So  is there any way to improve the stored procedure?

Comment: FYI: Adding `is_facility` to the index is no improvement. It's actually less efficient, since the index will be bigger, i.e. require more disk access to read.

Comment: @BlakeChen Nope. Without an index you're screwed. Of source, the DBA should be monitoring the system and see that excessive full scans are occurring, and create the index. Improves the load on the server.